# Seperate images from one larger image

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I have a set up similar to [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olgrs.png)

My goal is to take the image and grab the 8 cards of two different colors(white and yellow) and split each card into it's own image. The background is red and the cards are not always in the exact same spot. Logically, I would think I could somehow code for when it detects yellow or white to grab everything that isn't red to the right and downwards, and just continue through the image until that has been done for each card. I don't necessarily know if that's the best way or how I would translate that into code. Any help would be extremely appreciated. I would prefer to do this in Python. 
Each card has text on it and some have a secondary image on them.

Comment: Are your *"cards"* really boring pure, solid white and yellow with no details? It hardly seems worth extracting them.

Comment: No, they have text on them.

Comment: You could use Fred's (@fmw42) **ImageMagick** `multicrop` script from here - subject to licensing http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/multicrop/index.php

Comment: That looks perfect, however the installation instructions seem to no longer exist, any clue how to use it? Nevermind, seems I need to do it in linux! I'll start it up on my ubuntu os and give it a shot!